# Obtener Index de un objeto y Eliminar En Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Este es mi código esta basado en este https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/3p0j5sgy/

Pero no me obtiene el index del ciclo for,
Básicamente necesito un botón para eliminar el elemento al que se le de click.

El método `removeChild` no funciona.

ItemClean.vue

```
<template>
    <li>
    <div
      :class="{bold: isFolder}"
      >
      {{model.name}}
      <span v-show="!isFolder" class="remove" @click="changeType"> [Add] </span>
      <span class="remove" @click="removeChild(index)"> [Remove] </span>
    </div>
    <ul v-if="isFolder">
      <item-clean
        class="item"
        v-for="model, index  in model.children"
        :key="index"
        :model="model"
        >
      </item-clean>
      <li class="add" @click="addChild">+</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
          model: Object
        },
        data () {
          return {
          }
        },
        computed: {
          isFolder: function () {
            return this.model.children &&
              this.model.children.length
          }
        },
        methods: {
            changeType: function () {
              if (!this.isFolder) {
                Vue.set(this.model, 'children', [])
                this.addChild()
              }
            },
          addChild: function () {
            this.model.children.push({
              name: 'new stuff'
            })
          },

          //Esta funcion no me sirve ya que no obtiene el index
          removeChild: function(index){
            //Vue.delete(this.model, 'name')
            this.$delete(this.model.children, index);
          },
        }

    }
</script>

<style>
    .remove, .bold{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .bold{
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
```

index.html

```
    <ul id="item_clean">
      <item-clean
        class="item"
        :model="treeData">
      </item-clean>
    </ul>
```

app.js

```
const item_clean = new Vue({
  el: '#item_clean',
  data: {
    treeData: {
        name: 'My Tree',
        children: [
          { name: 'hello' },
          { name: 'wat' },
        ]
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza identificadores como [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) para cada elemento dentro del array de datos, de modo que te quede de la siguiente manera:

```
[
  {
     id: 'f6148255-d61c-4240-9801-ffff1db07a1b',
     name: 'music',
     children: [
       {
         id: '09a099a7-994f-4304-ad43-8c0c5068c32c',
         name: 'Prófugos - Soda Stereo',
       },
     ],
   }
]
```

De esta manera tendrás accesible el uuid de cada elemento para eliminar con más seguridad. Esto no lo harás en el modelo que has pasado, sino en el modelo padre para que **al eliminar el elemento se re-renderice el DOM** con la data actualizada.

```
<span class="remove" @click="removeChild(model.id)">Remove</span>
```

En el método `removeChild` realizas la petición mediante un [evento personalizado](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events) para que el padre elimine el elemento en cuestión:

```
removeChild(id) {
  this.$emit('remove', id); // el padre recibirá este evento
},
```

Por último, el padre debe **escuchar** por este evento. Esto se hace mediante el atributo [`v-on`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events):

```
<ul id="item_clean">
  <item-clean
    class="item"
    :model="treeData"
    v-on:remove="remove" // esto referenciará a un método 'remove'
  >
  </item-clean>
</ul>
```

Finalmente, defines el método `remove` en el elemento padre:

```
function remove(id) {
  const clone = Object.assign({}, this.threeData, {});
  const filter = (data = [], index = 0, id) => {
    if (index === clone.length - 1) { return; }
    const child = clone[index];
    
    if (child.id === id) {
      return clone.filter(c => c.id !== id);
    }
    
    if (child.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
      filter(child.children, id);
    } else {
      filter(clone, index + 1, id);
    }
  };
  this.threeData = filter(clone, id);
}
```

Este último método solo itera de forma recursiva el `treeData` y, cuando encuentra un elemento que coincide con el `id` a eliminar, elimina y detiene la ejecución, caso contrario mira si tiene hijos y vuelve a realizar el proceso.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizar el valor de index para eliminar un item de la lista no es lo que se recomienda, pero si aún lo deseas hacer has olvidado los parentesis en el html:

```
<item-clean
        class="item"
        v-for="(model, index)  in model.children"
        :key="index"
        :model="model"
        >
</item-clean>
```